# WDS is not started when invoked from SYSlinux menu

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, syslinux

I've configured WDS to use syslinux (I'm using Syslinux-6.04-pre2), and my boot configuration is to work only with UEFI/64

With my current setup, Linux boots are starting correctly when I select it from menu and are working fine.

But my problem is that I'm unable to start WDS from the SYSLINUX menu

My Setup: (%syslinux% is pointing to syslinux source)

```
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\efi\syslinux.efi g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\pxelinux.0
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\elflink\ldlinux\ldlinux.e64 g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\ldlinux.e64

copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\menu\menu.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\menu.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\menu\vesamenu.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\vesamenu.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\chain\chain.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\chain.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\modules\reboot.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\reboot.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\modules\poweroff.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\poweroff.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\lib\libcom32.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\libcom32.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\libutil\libutil.c32    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\libutil.c32

copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\modules\linux.c32 g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\linux.c32

copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\cmenu\libmenu\libmenu.c32 g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\libmenu.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\gpllib\libgpl.c32  g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\libgpl.c32
copy /y %syslinux%\efi64\com32\lua\src\liblua.c32  g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\liblua.c32

copy /y %syslinux%\bios\memdisk\memdisk    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\memdisk
copy /y g:\RemoteInstall\boot\x64\pxeboot.n12    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\pxeboot.0
copy /y g:\RemoteInstall\boot\x64\abortpxe.com    g:\remoteinstall\boot\x64\abortpxe.0
```

Then, I've created some entries on pxelinux.cfg folder using default file, to invoke linux setup, one of these is an entry to call Windows Deployment system

```
LABEL wds
MENU LABEL Windows Deployment Services
KERNEL pxeboot.0
```

Computer boots and shows the Syslinux menu, but when I select the WDS option from my menu it does nothing... simply nothing, and I don't have any idea about what could the problem.

Any idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: Syslinux is not designed to be pxe booted. They specifically built the PXElinux (an official fork of syslinux) project for such purposes. I have successfully built an instance with PXElinux. Check out this link for more details: https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX

Comment: If that fixes it for you, I will post it as an answer

Comment: i guess that my problem is with 'chainloading', because to boot WDS in UEFI mode I should boot with `bootmgfw.efi`, but when I try to boot using this file I'll have a error like this: `"Loading bootmgfw.efi ...OK" "Invalid Boot signature 0x0,bailing out" "Booting kernel failed:Bad file number" `